# Which Grammatical Form and how is it said in English

Tags: grammar-identification, perfect-tense

I am currently reading a book trying to improve my Deutsch and I came across some sentences with the following structure:

> wäre ich niemals mit unserem Hund rausgegangen
>
> und ich hätte auch nie ihn getroffen

There's a *Konjunktiv II* along with the *Perfekt*. What is such a grammatical form called? I get what they mean but what would be the grammatical equivalent of those sentences in English?

Answer (score 1):

The *Konjunktiv II* exists both in *Präteritum* and *Plusquamperfekt* forms. The *Präteritum* forms address the present, while the *Plusquamperfekt* forms address the past.

> Ich ginge bei diesem Wetter niemals mit unserem Hund raus.

*I would never walk the dog in this weather.*

I'm giving advice.

> Ich wäre bei diesem Wetter niemals mit unserem Hund rausgegangen.

*I would never had walked the dog in this weather.*

I'm talking about a person who does such silly things. It's too late for advice.

---

> So oft ich dort bin, ich träfe ihn nie.

*As much I am there, I would never meet him.*

I promise not to meet him.

> So oft ich dort war, ich hätte ihn nie getroffen.

*As much I was there, I would had never met him.*

I deny I had plans to meet him.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar term you are looking for would be

> Konjunktiv 2 in der Vergangenheit

There is no choice between Präteritum or Perfekt in Konjunktiv 2. The form is always based on Perkfekt with haben/sein in Konjunktiv 2 form.